# JMeter regex extractor forEach controller

Tags: variables, jmeter

I'm creating some tests with JMeter, the situation is very simple, I have a search page with a list of results, and I have to retrieve from this results some values to use in the next request.
Those results are around 350, I don't need them all.

I used the RegexExtractor to retrieve those results and it works (I setted it to retrieve just 10 results), but now I don't know how to access the results inside a LoopCounter.
The extractor put the results into a variable named Result.

The problem is that I don't know hot to build dinamically the name of a variable.
Do I have to use some function like _p()??
I can access the variable just putting the **static** name *Result_0_g1*

Inside the LoopCounter I putted also a Counter to store the loop count into the variable **index**

Thank you

EDIT:

SOLVED I have to write:

> ${__V(Result_${index}_g1)

Comment: The solution given here by the OP might work in context but it won't handle no matches on the regex and is generally needlessly complicated in comparison to jmeter's built-in solution.

Comment: ...You can post your solution as answer and accept it to close the issue - if you believe it's solved.

Comment: mm which are the built-in solution in this case? I've tried with the ForEach controller but it doesn't seem work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to reference the variable with the function:

```
${__V(Result_${index}_g1)
```

Comment: You need in this case not ${__V(Result_${index}_g1) but ${__V(Result_g${index}}: if there are more than one match jmeter will generate specific variables for each match, based on the variable name to which you are trying to extract - in your case Result_g0, Result_g1, ..., Result_gN. Look into this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10626762/993246.

Answer (score 1):

...Just for collection.
See also [this post](http://theworkaholic.blogspot.com/2011/07/looping-through-all-output-of-regexp.html) for another implementation (case without using ForEach Controller):

```
ThreadGroup 
    HttpSampler 
        Regex Extractor (variableName = links) 
    WhileController(${__javaScript(${C} < ${links_matchNr})}) 
        HTTPSampler use ${__V(links_${C})} to access the current result 
        Counter (start=1, increment=1, maximum=${links_matchNr}, referenceName=C)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) - it's specifically designed for this purpose and does exactly what you want.

Comment: It seems that the ForEach controller don't work if I put the Match No. in the regex extractor...The problem is that I want to retrieve just the first 10 results

Comment: Use a match number of -1, this returns all matches and creates the groups, then you can simply limit the foreach to 10 iterations using a counter. Quote from help text: "the ForEach Controller can be used to loop through the groups by using the input variable refName_g, and can also loop through all the groups in all the matches by using an input variable of the form refName_${C}_g, where C is a counter variable. "

Answer (score 0):

You may use [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller):

```
ThreadGroup
    YourSampler
        Regular Expression Extractor (match -1, any template)
    Foreach controller
        Counter(Maximum -> ${Result_matchNr} , Rf Name -> index)
        LinkSamplerUsingParsedData(use -> ${__V(Result_${index}_g1)}
```

Now, if you want to iterate to all groups, you need another foreach to do that. As you know which group represent what value, you can use this way.