# How come the regular expression extractor in jmeter does not always extract the same value?

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have two WebService(SOAP) Requests.  The responses of both web service calls are exactly the same structure-wise.  For web service call number 1, it has the following structure,

```
  <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">0</data>
  <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">650</data>
```

For web service call number 2, it has the following structure,

```
  <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">0</data>
  <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">10203</data>
```

Under each of these calls, I have a regular expression extractor.  The reference names are different; but everything is defined exactly the same.  The extractor has the following definitions.

```
Apply to: Main Sample Only
Response Field to check: Body
Regular Expression: <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">(\d+?)</data>
Template: $1$
Match No.: 0
```

For the web service call number 1, the extractor gets the value of 650, which is what I want.  But for the web service call number 2, the extractor actually gets the value of 0, which is NOT what I want.  What I want to get in the web service call number 2 is 10203.  My question is, why is it that the regular expression extractor definitions would return two different results?

Thanks in advance,
Monte

Comment: Why are you trying to parse XML with regex? It's a Bad Idea (TM)...

Comment: I am new to jMeter.  While doing some Google searches, some other people suggested to use regex and that's why I am using regex.  What would you recommend?

Comment: I have no experience with jMeter, but most languages have XML libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a match number of zero it will pull a value for your regular expression at random. 0 = Random Match, 1 = first match, 2 = second, etc...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  By changing the match number if the other web service calls, the values are extracted correctly now.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you've asked already [same question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10626762/993246).

1. Use either [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) or [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) - which one is more preferable for parsing xml, as mentioned in comments above, - with the single expression - (for RegEx Extractor: `<data xsi:type="soapenc:string">(.+?)</data>`, for XPath Extractor: `//data/text()` - to get ALL the matches.
   Then use corresponding generated variable to access match you need - via `${refName_2}` e.g. (to access 2nd match extracted by query to refName variable), this is actual for both RegEx and XPath Extractors, - or force RegEx Extractor to use specific match by default, via setting "Match No." (to 2 as per above example).
2. Use [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) with [xpath query](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) which will uniquely describe required value among the other: by fixed position - like `//data[position()=2]/text()` in your case (presume that first match is always 0 and you need the 2nd), - or by value - comparing match's text() to 0 like `//data[text()!=0]/text()`.

Answer (score 0):

I am puzzled by the `?` in your regular expression: `(\d+?)`.  This means "one or more digits, but optionally."

Given your input data from call number 1 and call number 2, I would expect it to match the first line in both cases, `<data xsi:type="soapenc:string">0</data>`, but you say that it doesn't.

I suspect that don't want to match a number with a leading zero.  So I would suggest

```
Regular Expression: <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">([1-9]\d*)</data>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given web service calls

For web service call number 1, it has the following structure

```
<data xsi:type="soapenc:string">0</data>
  <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">650</data>
```

For web service call number 2, it has the following structure

```
<data xsi:type="soapenc:string">0</data>
  <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">10203</data>
```

we can extract the values 650 from the web service call number1 in the following formats

```
</data>\s\s<data xsi:type="soapenc:string">(.+)</data>
or
</data>\s\s<data xsi:type="soapenc:string">([0-9]+)</data>
```

we can extract the values 10203 from the web service call number 2 in the following formats

```
</data>\s\s<data xsi:type="soapenc:string">(.+)</data>
or
</data>\s\s<data xsi:type="soapenc:string">([0-9]+)</data>
```